# Show png file on Web page

Tags: php, curl

All,

I am executing a PHP script through CURL which returns a PNG file as an output. How can I show the png file in a php web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<img src="urltotheimage.php" alt="Alt text" />';
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why do you need to fetch a PNG through CURL? There's better ways to get a image from server, for example using the `<img />` tag..

Anyways, I assume you are getting the binary data in a variable, you can output the image by setting appropriate headers and echoing the data:

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

Comment: The issue is i am generating the image using imagefrompng() function in pchart. When I try to display this on browser, I get a bunch of characters instead of the image file. I am not sure how to display that file in the browser

Comment: Then this method should work. The strange characters are the binary data of the PNG file which the browser tries to output as HTML. If you specify the proper content type (image/png), it should show up just fine.

Comment: I wanted to show multiple graphs on the same page. It's not working when called through an MVC controller-Model architecture.

Answer (score 0):

as you are receiving the string representing the png and if that is base64 encoded then you can embed directly on the image tag as follows:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhH..." />
```

where aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhH... would be the image string.

see more on data uri's here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Inclusion_in_HTML_or_CSS_using_PHP